# Error: MFC projects cannot define _ATL_NO_EXCEPTIONS

Tags: c++, mfc, atl

I'm extending an open source project. After including afxcoll.h in a new C++ file in order to use CStringArray, I get this error:

```
Error: MFC projects cannot define _ATL_NO_EXCEPTIONS
```

I suspect I'll be able to fix the error by adding #defines or changing or rearranging the inclusion of headers, or, if that's not possible, using something other than CStringArray. What are your suggestions?

Please ask questions in the comments for this question, not in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CAtlArray<CString>` instead of `CStringArray`, as this is compatible with  `_ATL_NO_EXCEPTIONS`. The ATL collection classes are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15e672bd.aspx). I normally prefer to use C++ standard library classes such as `std::vector` instead of the MFC container classes, though.

I'd suggest investigating why `_ATL_NO_EXCEPTIONS` is defined in this project and whether it can be removed.

Comment: answer chosen for your suggestion of using CAtlArray

Answer (score 1):

how about ... not defining _ATL_NO_EXCEPTIONS like the error says?

(Ooops thats a question as an answer).